# Replace values in a dataframe with values from another dataframe when common value is found in specific column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace `hours` in `df` with `hours` from `replacements` for project IDs that exist in both dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'project_ids': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'hours': [111, 222, 333, 444, 555],
    'else' :['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
})

replacements = pd.DataFrame({
    'project_ids': [2, 5, 3],
    'hours': [666, 999, 1000],
})

for project in replacements['project_ids']:
    df.loc[df['project_ids'] == project, 'hours'] = replacements.loc[replacements['project_ids'] == project, 'hours']

print(df)
```

However, only the project ID 3 gets correct assignment (1000), but both 2 and 5 get `NaN`:

```
 projects   hours else
0         1   111.0    a
1         2     NaN    b
2         3  1000.0    c
3         4   444.0    d
4         5     NaN    e
```

1. How can I fix it?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with another `Series` created by `replacements` with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
s = replacements.set_index('project_ids')['hours']
df['hours'] = df['project_ids'].map(s).fillna(df['hours'])
print(df)
   project_ids   hours else
0            1   111.0    a
1            2   666.0    b
2            3  1000.0    c
3            4   444.0    d
4            5   999.0    e
```

Comment: Thanks! Am I correct that `df['project_ids'].map(s)` is looking for each project ID from `df` in the index of `s`, and returns hours value for this index when found?

Comment: @barciewicz - exactly. And if no match, there are `NaN`s, which are replace by original by `.fillna(df['hours'])`

Answer (score 1):

Another way using [`df.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
m=df.set_index('project_ids')
m.update(replacements.set_index('project_ids')['hours'])
print(m.reset_index())
```

---

```
   project_ids   hours else
0            1   111.0    a
1            2   666.0    b
2            3  1000.0    c
3            4   444.0    d
4            5   999.0    e
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df_new = pd.merge(df, replacements, on='project_ids', how='left', suffixes=['_1', ''])
df_new['hours'].fillna(df_new['hours_1'], inplace=True)
df_new.drop('hours_1', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

```
print(df_new)
   project_ids else   hours
0            1    a   111.0
1            2    b   666.0
2            3    c  1000.0
3            4    d   444.0
4            5    e   999.0
```